# bash and awk performance with clear and cursor up command

Tags: performance, bash, awk

I'm testing Bash and AWK script performance about `clear` vs `tput clear` and `tput cuu1` (cursor up) commands. I implemented similar scripts in Bash and in AWK.

Bash: http://pastebin.com/0DSc0a71

AWK: http://pastebin.com/WAJ9inRx

admitting to have written them in a similar way, I analyze the different execution times.

in the Bash script:

- `clear` bash command is as fast as `tput clear` command
- and `tput cuu1` is very expensive

in the AWK script:

- `tput cuu1` is not expensive

@ with `system( "clear" );` @

- and `clear` bash command is slower than `tput clear` command

@ with `"clear" | getline Clear` ( http://pastebin.com/Afh3WFGR ) @

- and `clear` bash command is as fast as `tput clear` command

So it seems AWK performs better `tput cuu1` command than Bash and
into AWK script, `system()` function is slower that other direct recall.

@ adding cpu information @

The AWK script uses less CPU than bash script. The Bash script uses 4 times more CPU than the AWK script. Is it possible perform Bash script?

why is `tput cuu1` very expensive in a Bash script?

Comment: thank you @dennis-williamson because I modified awk script and now I recall clear and tput clear in similar way.

Comment: On my system, saving the output of `tput cuu1` into a variable then outputting it repeatedly, Bash does it slightly faster than AWK. How are you measuring "expense"?

Comment: On my system, awk script does it slightly faster than bash script and awk script uses less cpu than bash script. Using `tput cuu1` instead `$cuu` (`cuu='tput clear'`), I do not observe different behavior about cpu or speed. Do I something different than you?

Comment: I ran scripts with time command. I observed cpu / memory / load average and the differences are about speed and cpu usage. awk script is better than bash script about speed and cpu usage, on my system: Intel Core i7, 8 processors, 8Gb RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Both AWK and Bash are calling the same external `clear` and `tput` utilities. I suspect some of the difference may be in the exec overhead of one versus the other and the difference in the way your two scripts are implemented. On my system `clear` outputs the same sequence as `tput clear` and the docs say that's the case. Note that `clear` and `tput` are external utilities and not Bash or AWK commands.

Why do you want to do this? Use the language that's needed for other reasons. Save the sequence in a variable at the script's startup so you don't have to make repeated calls to `tput`. Only use `clear` for convenience since that's all it does - `tput` is obviously more versatile.

Comment: Thank you. I modified awk script and now I recall clear and tput clear in similar way. I begun to understand what is the best way to create a movie as "telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl". but immediately, the differences in performance have taken over!